# How can I implement authentication with Android and REST?

Tags: android, rest

What is the best way to authenticate android apps in a backend that its services are offered through calls rest. I read about oAuth, is it a good choise?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, OAuth2 is a good choice for authenticating apps. See http://soabits.blogspot.dk/2014/02/api-authentication-considerations-and.html for some considerations.